# Visual Studio Project not visible

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on VS2008. i have been given the project of Onlline Teachers Evaluation System. I was working in a WEBSITE named as Class. Last time i was working on it I made many changes. I added many new forms integrated them saved the changes and shut down the system. Now when i've opened it those files are simply not there in Class project. I had set the home.aspx as startup page. if i run it on local host it says homme page not found. The same thing happened before and i had to make whole thing again from scratch. Does anybody know what could be the reason??

Comment: Why aren't you using source control?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Visual Studio issue. The files you had previously saved simply aren't there. So the question is: why did the files disappear? I can think of 4 possible causes:

1. You're opening the wrong project: the project you worked on last time has the same name, but it's located at a different location on your disk.
2. Someone has installed version control on your system rolled back your changes.
3. Someone restored a backup image of your disk.
4. You have serious hardware problems.

Or maybe it's something else equally strange or unexpected. Hopefully knowing that Visual Studio has nothing to do with this will help you.

Comment: I have opened all the projects and websites of VS none of them has those files. isn't it possible to retrieve last successfully run project?

Comment: YES you were right I was opening the wrong folder thanks :)